# What would be a trivial or simple Time-of-check to time-of-use scenario in Bash?

Tags: bash, socket, database, terminology

Often when software development concepts are explained in Bash, I understand them better than say in JavaScript.

About Time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTOU) it was stated in [the current opening passage in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use):

> In software development, time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTOU, TOCTTOU
> or TOC/TOU) is a class of software bugs caused by a race condition
> involving the checking of the state of a part of a system (such as a
> security credential) and the use of the results of that check.

What would be a trivial or simple Time-of-check to time-of-use scenario in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common race condition of that type that I see on this site relates to the handling of process IDs (PIDs) and signalling based on these.

Someone may be using `ps`+`grep` to get a PID for some named process, and then `kill` to signal it.  Between getting the PID and signalling it, the PID may have gone away.  The use of `pkill` minimizes the window for this bug to happen.

In other scenarios, holding on to a PID and expecting it to always refer to the same process over an extended length of time (for example, in a "PID file"), could cause signals to be sent to the wrong processes.  This is because all Unix systems reuse PIDs.

Another common issue is file locking, i.e. using the filesystem to provide a locking mechanism for multi process synchronization and critical sections.   One may, for example test whether some "lock file" exists, and if it doesn't, create it and thereby "get the lock".  In-between checking for file existence and creating the lock file, there is a window of opportunity for some other process to also realize that the lock file doesn't exist:

```bsh
while [ -e "$lockfile" ]; do
    sleep 10
done
touch "$lockfile"
echo 'got lock'  # or did I?

# do work

rm -f "$lockfile"
```

The solution in *this* case is to use a dedicated file-locking tool like `flock`, or to use a lock *directory*, since `mkdir` is atomic:

```bsh
while ! mkdir "$lockdir" 2>/dev/null; do
    sleep 10
done
echo 'got lock'

# do work

rmdir "$lockdir"
```

This still would not work reliable on networking filesystems such as NFS, as these do not provide atomic operations for directory creation.

There are doubtlessly many other examples.

Comment: to use a lock directory, or a tool actually meant for creating lock files, which can then use `O_CREAT|O_EXCL`? (which still has problems on NFS, but IIRC there was some other solution that should work on it too)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, updated.